# writing article instead of asking question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I recently saw this question [How to start using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1879104) which answer is almost 7 pages long and the OP is saying he is still writing. My question is: is that appropriate to write an article on a FAQ form? Why not ask the OP to write it on his blog/website instead of writing his article at Stack Overflow?

Also in my view this is not merely useful.

Also should we flag for that kind of post?

Comment: The post in question is "not constructive" and I've closed it as such. Questions of the nature "what is better, when should I use" are not good fits for the site.  As its phrased now, your question boils down to that.  A good answer doesn't justify a bad question (not the first two paragraphs add no value either).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is that appropriate to write an article on a FAQ form?

Yes it is. We want answers here to end up being the definitive answer on the web for the question. The hope is that any other duplicate questions will end up getting closed with a link to the definitive answer.

> Why not ask the OP to write it on his blog/website instead of writing his article at Stack Overflow?

See the above.

> should we flag for that kind of post?

No. Why would you?

Comment: With the owners consent - for the purpose of that article and the community - it should be a CW entry

Comment: @Jon - Why? Why shouldn't the person answering be given the reputation for their efforts? And the post, after 8 edits will become CW automatically.

Comment: While I agree with this answer as applied to the general question of "can we post articles here", I disagree with the specific case that the OP brought up.  It's a *horrible* question for SO.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas - I agree that the linked question is not suitable. Frankly, I didn't even register the linked question, as the question here is about the _answer_...

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas i saw a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work sounds like same .... also shows no efforts .. but still here not closed  ... i think possible reason is it have good answer ....  ... if you think my post is  not constructive i can delete my post ...

Answer (score 4):

This type of 'blogging' on the site is officially [sanctioned and encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) as well as supported by the user interface:

[image: You can ask and answer at the same time while submitting]

Checking the box brings up an editor to compose an answer, allowing you to submit both the question *and* your answer at once.

As long as the question and answer meet our quality criteria, we welcome the contribution. Instances where duplication comes into question should be evaluated on a case by case basis. If the self answered 'blog style' question and answer provide substantially more context and information than something that exists, we'll obviously favor the better content when deciding *if* something else needs to be closed in light of the new contribution.

And yes, the person taking the time to share their knowledge *should* receive reputation for doing so, provided that the knowledge is reasonably composed, relevant and useful - just like any other question or answer.

Don't treat these types of questions any differently when deciding if something warrants a flag. Flags that *just* point out that someone simply used the facilities that we have in place will probably be declined.

Comment: I'm answering a few more questions than this question actually asked, because this has come up several times recently in flags.